# How should i interpret a loop inside a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am wondering how this code does the job.I don't understand how n and i written in the for loops lead to [0 1].

If `dpn=1` and `conn=[0 1]` then the result of below code will be `eft=[0 1]`

```
eft = numpy.array([dpn * n + i for n in conn for i in range(dpn)])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `numpy.array()` call simply transforms a python list into a numpy array. The whole logic happens inside the list comprehension. You can read up on list comprehensions here:
https://hackernoon.com/list-comprehension-in-python-8895a785550b

A list comprehension can also be written as a for-loop, in this case there are two nested loops:

```
eft = []

for n in conn:
  for i in range(dpn):
    eft.append(dpn * n + i)
```

It is basically just a concise way to create a new list based on some other iterable(s).